# Edit class constants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Letter model. It defines two different send-methods for sending the letter as a hash:

```
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
  SEND_METHODS = {
  'Paper' => 0,
  'Online' => 1
}
```

In some cases, the send-method **Online** is not available and so I delete it in the *new* and *edit* action of the controller:

```
 @send_methods = Letter::SEND_METHODS
 if letter.paper?
   @send_methods.delete 'Online'
 end
```

I see, that this code smells. (It would be better, if the letter model has a method, which gives me the hash, with the right entries.) But that's not the point.

I experienced strange behaviour with this code. Although, I assigned the class constant *Letter::SEND_METHODS* to the instance variable *@send_methods*, the *@send_methods*-hash sometimes didn't have the entry *{ 'Online' => 1 }*, even though *letter.paper?* was *false*. I observed, that *@send_methods* sometimes don't have the entry *{ 'Online' => 1 }* direct after the assignment.

My explanation is, that *@send_methods* is assigned by reference, but Ruby do always assign by value...

Who can wise my up?

Comment: *"It defines two different methods for sending the letter as a hash"* - how? It just sets two key-value-pairs. Where is this `Online` method?

Comment: Try this in IRB: `a={foo:1,bar:2}; b=a; b.delete(:foo)` and inspect `a` afterwards (`foo` is gone).

Comment: @stefan i edit the text. Online is not a method, it's only a Key in the hash.

Comment: "but Ruby do always assign by value" - and that value is the reference. :)

Comment: I know that delete,  deletes entries. ;) But the entry is deleted globally - in subsequent  requests.

Comment: @sergio so it's assigned by reference? ;)

Comment: Probably because the key is deleted from `Letter::SEND_METHODS`, too. Both, `@send_methods` and `Letter::SEND_METHODS` reference the same hash.

Comment: No, it's not assigned by reference. It's assigned by value. If it were assigned by reference, then `@send_methods = 42` would also change `Letter::SEND_METHODS` to `42`. But Ruby is not a functional language. If you change an object, that object changes, regardless of what name you call that object. My mom calls me "son" and my colleagues call me "Jörg". If I cut my hair, my hair is gone, it doesn't magically reappear just because someone refers to me by a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is missing because you are deleting it:

```
SEND_METHODS = {'Paper' => 0, 'Online' => 1}

@send_methods = SEND_METHODS
@send_methods.delete('Online')

SEND_METHODS
#=> {"Paper"=>0}
```

This can be avoided by freezing the hash:

```
SEND_METHODS = {'Paper' => 0, 'Online' => 1}.freeze

@send_methods = SEND_METHODS
@send_methods.delete('Online') #=> RuntimeError: can't modify frozen Hash
```

You have to [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-dup) the hash (create a copy) in order to modify it:

```
@send_methods = SEND_METHODS.dup
@send_methods.delete('Online')

@send_methods
#=> {"Paper"=>0}

SEND_METHODS
#=> {"Paper"=>0, "Online"=>1}
```